# How to calculate average of values in a Python Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

My Python Pandas data frame has 2 columns for salary(Amount) and total number of employees(Staff) receiving that particular salary (10 employees get $300, 20 employees get $200 & 30 employees get $100).I'm supposed to calculate the average salary of all employees. Is there any way to do that? I'm fairly new to Python Pandas so any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
   Amount  Staff
0     100     30
1     200     20
2     300     10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `mean` by defintion - sum / counts:

```
s = df.assign(Amount = df["Amount"].mul(df["Staff"])).sum()
print (s)
Amount    10000
Staff        60
dtype: int64

print (s.Amount / s.Staff)
166.66666666666666
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as you described - no special techniques.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   Amount  Staff
0     100     30
1     200     20
2     300     10"""), sep="\s+")

(df["Amount"] * df["Staff"]).sum() / df["Staff"].sum()
```

**output**

```
166.66666666666666
```